# React webpack and redux add css and Components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux

I found on web this [tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup/). I set react application according to tutorial and all is OK. But now i would like add css file and divide application on components how is in this [tutorial](https://blogg.kantega.no/webapp-with-create-react-app-and-spring-boot/) . I would like show default page after run command `npm start` . But when I added css file and App.jsx and wrote: `npm start` I got error:

> ERROR in ./src/App.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App.css' in '/Users/username/Documents/Projects/myApp/frontend/src'
>    @ ./src/App.js 21:0-19
>    @ ./src/index.js
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/index.js

Thank you for your advice on how to set up your app to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the default folder structure you get when you use create-react-app. It looks like you have the location of the css file wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

> npm install style-loader
>
> npm install css-loader

and edit webpack.config.js how is in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49425633/3468921).